# $\{(x, y) \mid x, y \in \mathbb{N}, x|y \;\mathrm{and}\; y|x\}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Is it a function? If not explain why. I've been fiddling around with it for a minute, and I can't seem to get a straight forward answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also, if someone could tell me how to insert the proper symbols, that would be awesome! Alt codes don't seem to work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x|y$ and $y|x$ then we have $y=x$ or $y=-x$. But since $x,y\in \mathbb N$ then $y=x$ is accepted. That is the above function is the identity function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thank you sir! Its appreciated!